# Actualizar valor do campo Usando TableAdaptar C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

Saudacoes!

Estou trabalhando com DataSet para modificar dados na BD sql.Tenho uma TableAdapter alocada a um formulário onde alguns dos campos estao *linkados* aos textboxs. Acontece que alguns dos campos eu nao quero mostrar no textbox mas quero actualizar os seus valores via código. Como faco isso??

Eis o código pra salvar os dados:

```
private void clBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.Validate();

    micro.cl.Rows[0]["clstamp"] = "vc233546xxz";

    this.clBindingSource.EndEdit();
    clTableAdapter.Update(micro.cl);

}

//"micro" é o nome da minha Dataset
//A minha table "cl" contém 3 campos: codigo,nome e clstamp.
//o codigo e o nome sao introduzidos pelo utilizador, enquando que o clstamp 
//será uma chave aleatoria que será gerada ao gravar, e ela n precisa ser 
//mostrada ao utilizador.
```

Comment: Olá @VirgilioCossa, bem vindo ao **StackOverflow**. Aproveite para dar uma olhada ao [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor como colocar de forma correta uma questão. Quanto à sua, pode pf colocar o código que está a usar? Ajuda-nos a perceber melhor o problema, mas de qualquer forma parece-me que a solução será remover o _link_ aos controlos que não pretende atualizar de forma automática.